# Having a runtime error of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 97

Tags: java, arrays

I am having an error, can someone please help me out. I am trying to print highest occurring vowel in the string.

```
void vowelCount() {
    int countO = 0 ,countU = 0,countI = 0 ,countA = 0 ,countE = 0  ;
    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    int[] count = new int[] {countA,countE,countI,countO ,countU};
    int maxCount = 0;
    char maximumChar = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < TEXT.length(); i++) {
        char ch = TEXT.charAt(i);
        if (ch == vowels[0]) {
            countA++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[1]) {
            countE++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[2]) {
            countI++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[3]) {
            countO++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[4]) {
            countU++;
        }


    }

    for( int i = 0; i< vowels.length ; i++) {
        if (count[vowels[i]] > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count[vowels[i]];
            maximumChar = vowels[i];
    }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The most used lowercase vowel is " + maximumChar + " for " + maxCount + " times.");
 }
```

Arrayindexoutofbound exception results, i am not quite sure where could me my error. Tried for such a long time still the error repeats.

Comment: Please add the error logs. It tells you which line you encountered the exception at. Tell the line too.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying it gives me error on line number

Comment: `count[vowels[i]]` is probably your problem. `vowels[i]` will not be in the range `[0..4]` and hence you exceed the bounds of your array. I think you might want `count[i]`.

Comment: for( int i = 0; i< vowels.length ; i++) {

Comment: yes, dave it is.Thanks for replying though.

Comment: DAVE, I understand what you are trying to say but I am trying to iterate it over vowels So that I can get the maximum occurring vowel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that `count[vowels[i]]` is your problem. `vowels[i]` will not be in the range `[0..4]` and hence you exceed the bounds of your array. You want `count[i]` instead. You could try the following simplified code

```
void vowelCount() {
    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    int[] count = new int[vowels.length];
    int maxCount = 0;
    char maximumChar = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < TEXT.length(); i++) {
        char ch = TEXT.charAt(i);
        for (int j=0; j<vowels.length; j++) {
            if (ch == vowels[j]) {
                count[j]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<vowels.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count[i];
            maximumChar = vowels[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The most used lowercase vowel is " + maximumChar + " for " + maxCount + " times.");
}
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here - `if (count[vowels[i]] > maxCount) {`

`vowels[i]` will give you a vowel that is a `char`. When used as index to fetch from char array, the character gets converted into its ASCII value, which wont be in the range of 0 to 4.

I would say, you should try to find your mistakes, rather than finding a solution. Your following code doesn't do what you expect.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TEXT.length(); i++) {
        char ch = TEXT.charAt(i);
        if (ch == vowels[0]) {
            countA++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[1]) {
            countE++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[2]) {
            countI++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[3]) {
            countO++;
        }
        if (ch ==  vowels[4]) {
            countU++;
        }

    }
```

When you are updating the variables with `countX++`, it isn't modifying the values stored in the `count[]` array, because you already initialised them with `0`s i.e. the initial values of `countX`.

Comment: thanks for replying uneq95, I never knew this thing thanks for letting me know but is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because of these lines:

```
if (count[vowels[i]] > maxCount) {
        maxCount = count[vowels[i]];
        maximumChar = vowels[i];
}
```

Here the `vowels[i]` is having chars, when you use it as `count[vowels[i]]` you are using the ascii value of the char stored in the `vowels` array as an index to access the value in the `count` array. 
In the exception 97 is printed as it is the ascii value of the char 'a'.

You should increment the `count` array data instead of the variables `countO, countU, etc..` variables. You also need to iterate through the `count` array and find the max number from it and also assign the character from the `vowel` array to the `maximumChar` variable.

```
static String TEXT = "teeaaaiist";
static void vowelCount() {
        int countO = 0 ,countU = 0,countI = 0 ,countA = 0 ,countE = 0  ;
        char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        int[] count = new int[] {countA,countE,countI,countO ,countU};
        int maxCount = 0;
        char maximumChar = ' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < TEXT.length(); i++) {
            char ch = TEXT.charAt(i);
            if (ch == vowels[0]) {
                count[0]++;
            }
            if (ch ==  vowels[1]) {
                count[1]++;
            }
            if (ch ==  vowels[2]) {
                count[2]++;
            }
            if (ch ==  vowels[3]) {
                count[3]++;
            }
            if (ch ==  vowels[4]) {
                count[4]++;
            }
        }

        for( int i = 0; i< count.length ; i++) {
            if (count[i] > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count[i];
                maximumChar = vowels[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The most used lowercase vowel is " + maximumChar + " for " + maxCount + " times.");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vowelCount();
    }
```